# Quelle est l’origine de « plaît-il ? »

Tags: étymologie, expressions-idiomatiques, questions

Quelqu’un trouve-t-il une référence pour déterminer d’où vient cette expression ? Le TLF [dit](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/plait-il?) que cela vient du verbe plaire, mais je ne trouve rien de plus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lu sur le forum l'[ABC de la langue française](http://www.languefrancaise.net/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=17914).

L'expression « plaît-il » serait une façon de signaler qu'on a entendu, et qu'on attend la suite, dont les origines remontent au XVIIe.
Cela dit je suis partagé avec l'explication de [Piotr](http://www.languefrancaise.net/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=17905#p17905) qui estime que c'est une « élision » du genre « (vous) *plaît-il* (de répéter)? » qui rejoint la façon de l'utiliser dans mon entourage.

Comment: Dans la mesure où j'y retrouve (enfin, merci !) le sens des mots, je préfère l'explication de Piotr. (Jusqu'à présent, je trouvais l'expression tellement déplacée du sens que j'y voyais que je me prenais à employer la forme littéralement, pour *est-ce qu'il plaît* …)

Answer (score 1):

En Haïti cette expression « plaît-il » est passée il y a fort longtemps dans la langue créole (« pletil »), où elle existe toujours et d'une manière beaucoup moins rare qu'en français. Je l'ai entendue plus d'une fois, et toujours chez des employés ou des domestiques qu'on avait appelés (pour leur demander de faire quelque chose). Dans ce contexte (de servitude venant directement de l'ancien régime), je crois que le sens « que puis-je faire pour vous plaire ? » est plus plausible.

Answer (score 0):

[*S'il vous plaît*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/S'il%20te/vous%20pla%C3%AEt) ? On peut lire au *LBU14* (§ 1105 d 3) que *s'il vous plaît* est utilisé en Belgique lorsqu'on *présente quelque chose* ou pour *faire répéter* ; dans le premier cas il s'agit en français plus régulier de *voici, voilà, je vous en prie* et, dans le second, de *[plaît-il](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/plaire/61329/locution?q=pla%C3%AEt-il#164517), pardon, comment, hein, quoi*, en ordre décroissant de politesse. Dans les deux cas, on a un emploi équivalent possible avec *s'il vous plaît* en France (observé pour le premier cas à Auch, Saint-Pierre d'Entremont, Nice, Cambrai, Belleville, Châlons-sur-Marne, et Paris). Au *DHLF/Rey*, on traite uniquement du deuxième cas pour la Belgique, qu'on associe à l'ancien *plaît-il* en France qui serait en effet [vieilli](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plait-il). Le *TLFi* renvoie à l'étymologie de [plaire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/plaire) où l'on situe ça autour de 1480 sous la forme *plest-il?* (idem *DHLF/Rey*) dans le *Mistere Viel Testament*, et il s'agit donc de la fin du 15<sup>e</sup>, bien avant l'exemple chez Molière. On l'a [catégorisé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plaire) sous des constructions de type *il plaît à qqn de* + infinitif., *il plaît à qqn que* + prop. complétive (voir aussi [*DmF*](http://atilf.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?IDF=dmfXhgYrmXart.revusYpXcda;ISIS=isis_dmf2015.txt;MENU=menu_dmf;OUVRIR_MENU=1;OO1=2;OO2=1;s=s025118fc;LANGUE=FR;FERMER;AFFICHAGE=2;MENU=menu_dmf;;XMODE=STELLa;FERMER;XXX=4;;)), dans un contexte de déférence avec le langage de la politesse, en interrogative. [Historiquement](http://artflsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=plaire) l'[*Académie française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/plaire) l'associe à « *Que vous plaît-il ? que demandez-vous de moi ?* », comme le fait le [*Littré*](http://www.littre.org/definition/plaire).

[image]

<sup>[ Ds. le sens des aiguilles : (1) Extrait avec « plest il ? » ds. [*Le mistère du viel testament*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5055x/f284.item) T. 5, (15<sup>e</sup>), publ. baron de Rothschild / (2) Extrait du [*Dictionnaire étymologique et historique du galloroman*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/196979) (français et dialectes d’oïl, francoprovençal, occitan, gascon) (FEW) / (3) Exemple chez *de Baif* (16<sup>e</sup>) au [Godefroy (Complément)](http://micmap.org/dicfro/previous/complement-godefroy/349/10/PLAIRE) / (4) Extrait du [*Dictionnaire universel, contenant généralement tous les mots françois*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k56749155/f256.item) [...] T. 3, Antoine Furetière, seconde éd. ]</sup>

---

C'est entre autres un tour impersonnel de la fin du 15<sup>e</sup> en formule de politesse soit vieillie ou appuyée, avec le verbe *plaire*, du type [*pardon*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pardon) interrogatif. S'il vous plaît !