# « Plaise (à) quelqu'un/quelque chose (de) + infinitif » : et le « à » là-dedans, variante particulière ?

Tags: prépositions, oral, subjonctif, droit-et-justice, registre

> (1) Monsieur mon maître, plaise humblement Votre Seigneurie accepter
>   que je n'aie pas confiance en Votre Seigneurie. ([Claudel](https://books.google.com/books?id=5laMAEvpz9wC&lpg=PP1&dq=soulier%20de%20satin%20I%2C7&pg=PA91#v=onepage&q=plaise&f=false))
>   (2) Plaise au ciel vous tenir en sa faveur commune. (Courteline)
>   (3) Plaise à la chambre condamner ma cliente à l'amende. (Hugo)
>   (4) Plaise à M. le juge de paix d'appliquer le maximum de la peine.
>   (Flaubert)

Au [*TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/plaire) on présente la **formule de requête** : *Plaise (à) qqn (de)* + infinitif, *plaise (à) qqn que* + proposition complétive, et on classe la citation de Claudel, qui ne relève pas du contexte du tribunal, comme vieillie, alors qu'on range celle de Hugo et Flaubert sous la rubrique *Droit* ; dans [*Ac.9*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/plaire) on traite uniquement de *plaise à la cour/au tribunal*.

En ce qui a trait à l'infinitif sujet logique d'un verbe impersonnel, *il me plaît* se construit parfois, selon l'usage classique, en langue littéraire, sans la préposition *de* pour introduire l'infinitif (1-3), nous dit *LBU14* (§ 912 c ; on donne les citations de Claudel (1) et de Courteline (2), entre autres). Furetière dans une première édition de son [*Dictionnaire*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=nCiGIkecOOgC&vq=plaise&hl=fr&pg=PA143) donne un exemple « Plaise à Mr. le Président avoir pour recommandé le bon droit de... » où la préposition *de* est absente (devant *avoir*). Mais nulle part on ne traite de la préposition (*à*) qui suit le subjonctif dans ces phrases optatives. Et au final elle manque seulement dans la citation de Claudel (1).

---

- Doit-on en déduire que la formule sans la préposition *à* est
  vieillie ou va-t-elle dans le sens de l'usage classique, plus
  littéraire (sans la préposition *de*), ou est-ce tout emploi à l'extérieur du domaine du droit qui soit vieilli ? Doit-on
  plutôt ranger la formule comme chez *Larousse* en la réduisant à
  [*plaise*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/plaire/61329/locution) ? Peut-on tenter de concilier le sources ou
  s'en référer à d'autres plus spécialisées ?
- Connaît-on un usage distinct en *droit* où l'on utilise une phrase
  optative comme d'un appel de lettre en début de plaidoirie à l'oral
  et non pour la recherche d'un moyen ou d'une conclusion à l'écrit,
  mais sans infinitif ni proposition complétive apparente qui ne suive,
  et ressemblant à : « Plaise (à) la cour, M<sup>es</sup> Untel, Unetelle,
  pour les appelants. » ; le cas échéant est-ce avec ou sans 
  préposition *à* ; peut-on analyser la phrase sous l'angle de ses référents ?

Comment: Je passe… (I'll pass)

Comment: Il n'y a pas de sens caché dans mon commentaire, je passe simplement la main à ceux ou celles qui sauront répondre à ces questions.

Answer (score 2):

C'est une question difficile à laquelle je vais essayer de donner un début de réponse.

A savoir qu'une phrase commençant par "plaise" est quoi qu'il arrive vieillie. Il n'est plus d'usage dans le français courant, que ça soit à l'oral ou à l'écrit.

Il reste aujourd'hui dans le domaine du droit l'utilisation de "Plaise à la cour" qui est une formule de politesse qui sert à demander à ce que la cour aille dans le sens de la personne formulant la requête. C'est utilisé à l'écrit mais aussi à l'oral.

Pour ce qui est de Plaise + sujet + infinitif c'est une très vieille formule qui n'est plus utilisée, à l'époque de Claudel elle ne l'était déjà plus vraiment mais en poésie on fait souvent appel à de vieilles formulations pour mettre en scène le décor plus rapidement que dans un livre.

Bonus : On utilise encore la formulation "Plait-il" qui à l'origine servait seulement à dire que l'on avait mal entendu ou mal compris. Aujourd'hui c'est utilisé avec humour quand on dit quelque chose qui nous embête pour faire comme si nous avions mal compris la phrase.

J’espère avoir aidé, même si des personnes plus compétentes que moi ont probablement une bien meilleure réponse.

Comment: p.s. _plaît-il_, oui je ne connaissais pas avant hier. J'ai fait une brève recherche là-dessus ([voir ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/23056/3177)). Merci !

Comment: Désolé peut être ai-je mal compris la question. La phrase du point (2) possède effectivement la préposition "à" vu que "à le" => "au". Peut être les canadiens ont gardés la version désuète, je n'en sais rien. Dans mon commentaire j'ai précisé que dans le language juridique Français la préposition était (dans tous les cas que j'ai rencontré) présente. Il est très rare de voir plaise sans préposition car désuet, cependant elle est correcte et n'a aucun impact sur le sens de la phrase. Si je peux améliorer ma réponse n'hésitez pas pour que ça profite à tout le monde.