# « (Dans le/en) sens (inverse/contraire) des aiguilles d'une montre » : précisions, options ?

Tags: locutions, synonymes, origine-ou-raison, antonyme, ellipse

Dans la légende d'une image présentée dans une [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/23056), on donne des indications de lecture de l'image avec un *syntagme d'emploi fréquent* (TLFi) :

> Dans le sens des [aiguilles](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aiguilles) d'une montre...

On peut imaginer qu'on ne retrouvait sans doute pas le syntagme avant que le mot [*montre*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/montre/1) ne soit utilisé pour désigner le *cadran d'horloge*, entre la fin du 15<sup>e</sup> et la fin du 16<sup>e</sup>. Par ailleurs [*Wiktionnaire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/dans_le_sens_des_aiguilles_d%E2%80%99une_montre) parle de la locution nominale et dit qu' « [h]istoriquement c'est le sens du mouvement de l'ombre du style d'un cadran solaire horizontal dans l'hémisphère nord » et on a des synomymes comme sens *anti-trigonométrique*, *horaire*, *horlogique*, *négatif*, *rétrograde* et l'[antonyme](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sens_inverse_des_aiguilles_d%E2%80%99une_montre), le *sens inverse/contraire des aiguilles d'une montre*.

---

- A-t-on une idée plus précise de l'**origine** du syntagme *dans le sens
  des aiguilles d'une montre* avec un exemple choisi ou d'autres précisions ?
- Avec l'antonyme, est-il plus usuel d'utiliser la **préposition** *dans*
  avec l'article *le* (*dans le sens inverse...*) ou la préposition *en*
  seule (*en sens inverse des...*) ?
- L'**ellipse** de la *montre* est-elle possible/usuelle (*dans le sens des
  aiguilles*) ; celle des *aiguilles* avec l'antonyme (*dans le sens
  contraire*) ?
- Reconnaît-on les **synonymes** présentés au *Wiktionnaire* ; connaît-on
  d'autres synonymes plus usuels ou incidemment d'autres manières d'exprimer la
  disposition d'éléments visuels dans l'espace autour d'un axe ou
  autrement ?

---

<sup>Une *montre* : La « [*Marie-Antoinette*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marie-Antoinette_(montre)) », de [Breguet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Breguet) (1837) :</sup>
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rapidement :

- l'origine a l'air d'être simplement la description d'un sens de rotation connu par tous;
- l'antonyme est *"dans le sens contraire des aiguilles d'une montre"*;
- je n'ai jamais entendu l'expression utilisée avec une ellipse;
- je n'en connais pas, pensiez-vous à quelque chose en particulier?

Comment: Merci ! J'ai pensé à un homophone de _cadran_. J'ai des idées au sujet des coordonnées etc. Mais la manière de guider l’œil qui n'est pas naturelle selon les points forts d'une image, dépend beaucoup de la conception de l'image et de son agencement. Par exemple est-ce que _dans le sens des aiguilles d'une montre_ est bien senti si l'image est essentiellement un triangle plutôt qu'un carré ou un cercle ? Et si il y a des blancs/espaces entre 4 carrés de tailles différentes non disposés symétriquement ? Quels mots guident l’œil ?

Comment: @Ange-à-Liberté Je ne suis pas sur de voir exactement de quoi tu parles, peut être qu'avec une image? Je pense qu'à partir du moment où le sens de rotation apparaît clairement, l'expression peut être utilisée. La représentation de la rotation de l'image dépend après de l'abstraction spatiale de chacun.