# Express "clockwise and anticlockwise direction"

Tags: traduction, anglais, mathématiques, science

Which way is better to express clockwise/anticlockwise direction? E.g.

> As seen against the background stars, the Earth rotates in a clockwise direction.
>
> Comme on le voit sur les étoiles à l'arrière-plan, la Terre tourne dans le sens des aiguilles d'une montre.

or

> Comme on le voit sur les étoiles à l'arrière-plan, la Terre tourne en sens horaire.

or another structure?

As another example

> The matrix describes an anticlockwise rotation of 30 degrees of the continuum about the z axis.
>
> La matrice décrit une rotation de 30 degrés du milieu continu en sens anti-horaire autour de l'axe z.

Following this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clockwise%2Canticlockwise&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclockwise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canticlockwise%3B%2Cc0) can someone use clockwise/anticlockwise in French?

Comment: Forcément... ;-) , j'ai toujours préféré *trigonométrique* à *anti-horaire*. Mais c'est perso évidemment.

Comment: Affirmer que la terre tourne dans le sens des aiguilles d'une montre n'est bien sûr qu'une convention essentiellement due au fait que ceux qui l'ont établie vivaient dans l'hémisphère nord...

Comment: Pour autant que je sache, vue du pôle nord, la terre tourne dans le *sens direct* == *trigonométrique* == ***anti**horaire*

Comment: @toto Très juste. Après réflexion, si notre civilisation était née dans l'hémisphère sud, les aiguilles des montres tourneraient peut-être dans le sens inverse que celui  que nous connaissons aujourd'hui, en considérant que ce sens est hérité du sens de l'ombre de l'aiguille des cadrans solaires.

Comment: @jlliagre: Tout à fait. Mon commentaire est juste pour signaler que vue du pôle Nord, la terre tourne dans le sens direct (ou antihoraire), ce qui est d'ailleurs une convention acceptée par tous les astronomes, **contrairement** à ce qui est dit dans la question ;)

Comment: Voir aussi [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23060/dans-le-en-sens-inverse-contraire-des-aiguilles-dune-montre-pr%C3%A9cision).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Clockwise* n'est pas utilisé en français (NGram rapporte de faux positifs).

Le formule de loin la plus courante est *dans le sens des aiguilles d'une montre*, et pour *counterclockwise*, le plus courant est *sens inverse des aiguilles d'une montre* mais on dit aussi souvent *sens contraire des aiguilles d'une montre*.

A l'écrit, *dans le sens horaire* (*sens antihoraire*) est en progression. On pourra l'utiliser dans un document scientifique, ainsi que *dans le sens trigonométrique* (*sens antitrigonométrique*) pour le sens inverse.

[image]

Comment: Merci ! Et la préposition ? Ça sera dans le sens horaire/antihoraire/trigonométrique comme dans le sens des aiguilles d'une montre ou en sens horaire/antihoraire/trigonométrique ?

Comment: Et antihoraire est-il acceptable ou est-ce mieux anti-horaire ?

Comment: Il vaut mieux écrire *antihoraire* (et *antitrigonométrique*).

Comment: Merci encore pour la réponse et le commentaire. Cependant, ci-dessus dans un autre commentaire je vois anti-horaire:-)!

Comment: Oui, les deux s'écrivent et personne ne s'offusquera de cette version. Le TLFi ne connait cependant que [la version sans tiret](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/anti-).

Comment: Alors si je bien comprends, p.ex., antisoviétique, anti soviétique, anti-soviétique existent tous les trois dans la langue française mais la préférence/suggestion du TLFi est d'utiliser le premier ?

Comment: La tendance est de privilégier la soudure. http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1463

Comment: C'est parfait ! J'ai bien compris maintenant.

Answer (score 3):

Pour le *counterclockwise*, afin de compléter l'excellente réponse de @jlliagre, on dit:

> Dans le sens inverse des aiguilles d'une montre.

Answer (score 3):

On peut également parler de *sens direct* (antihoraire) et de *sens rétrograde* (horaire).

Vue du pôle nord, la Terre tourne en sens direct, sur elle-même ainsi qu'autour du Soleil comme toutes les planètes et les planètes naines. Exceptés Vénus et Uranus qui tournent sur elles-mêmes en sens rétrograde.